git rebase --rebase-merges not preserving merge order
I have a repo that looks like this...
-+----*----*------*-------------------------  Main
  \------------+---------+------+-- Dev
   \-*--*--*--/-*--*--*-/-*--*-/  Feature1

That's my best attempt at ASCII art anyway. I'm actually using gitgraph in VS Code to visualize my repo.
The *s represent commits and the slashes are merges.
So basically I started a Dev branch off of my Main branch. Then from Dev, I started a Branch called Feature1 (for the purposes of this example anyway).  After several commits, I merged Feature1 onto Dev, but kept adding commits to Feature1 and merging to Dev.
Also there were other commits merged into Main during this time.
Now I want to rebase Dev onto Main. So I issue the command git rebase MAIN --rebase-merges. What I expect is something like this
  --*--*--*-+------------+---------+------+-- Main
             \-*--*--*--/-*--*--*-/-*--*-/  

What I get is more like this
  -*--*--*-+-----------------------------+--+--+
            \--------------------*--*---/--/--/
             \----------*--*--*--------/--/
              \--*--*-*---------------/

I've tried passing -i to the rebase and editing the todo script.  It has all the merges at the end.  Then I tried moving them where they should logically go, but I end up with just a flat line with no merge history at all.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I Googled for documentation of the todo script because there are reset commands in there too that I don't know what they do or how they interact with the merge command. But there was too much noise in the Google results. And a lot of old results recommending a command line option that was removed years ago.
Would this have worked better if my Dev branch had looked like this instead?
  \------------+-----------+------+-- Dev
   \-*--*--*--/\--*--*--*-/\-*--*-/  Feature1


I tested your scenario by reproducing the commit graph, and with git rebase --rebase-merges Main I got the desired outcome. At first I thought that the no-fast-forward merge that you have in the Dev branch would be hard to reproduce automatically, but it worked perfectly. So...

Well, except, of course, that after the rebase operation, I end up on branch Dev, and Main is not yet advanced to new Dev. But that is just a matter of git branch -f Main Dev.

I seem to have stumbled upon the magic incantation to use in the todo file when doing git rebase main -i --rebase-merges
As I said, it put all of the merge commands at the end of the script.
I edited it so that it looked like:
# Branch branch-name-1
label branch-point-1
pick 123456789 description
pick 897312987 description
label branch-name-1
reset branch-point-1
merge -C 098234589 branch-name-1 # Merge pull request #123 from branch-name

# Branch branch-name-2
label branch-point-2
pick 09845abce description
pick 987dicabe description
label branch-name-2
reset branch-point-2
merge -C 903478028 branch-name-2 # Merge pull request #123 from branch-name

# etc

Each section had a reset command after the comment and before the first pick.  I replaced that with a label. The name for the label is unimportant but must be unique and is what you use on the reset command just before the merge.
I copied the merge commands from where they were at the end of the script so that I didn't have to worry about hash was.
The resulting graph isn't exactly what it was before, but it's as close as I could get and much cleaner than the overlapping thing it was giving me before.

If I am reading your chart correctly (no merges of dev into main or the other way around since they diverged), you could pull it off by doing
git rebase --rebase-merges main dev

Then dev (with all the merges and stuff) will look to have started from the tip of main instead of a few commits behind the tip.
UPDATE
If you had done merges of dev into main, then probably the best you can do to get the result you want is to first get a straight history of main that has no merges from dev (say, in a main-no-dev-merges branch), and then run the rebase:
git rebase --rebase-merges main-no-dev-merges dev


is git rebase --rebase-merges main dev different from just doing git rebase --rebase-merges main if dev is the current branch?

It would be the same thing.

Create a new branch for each feature iteration instead of continuing to commit to the same branch after merging. This creates a cleaner history that rebases more predictably.
If you must use the first pattern presented by your graph, you might want to consider using git merge --squash when merging Feature1 into Dev. This would flatten the feature branch commits into a single commit each time, making the history easier to rebase.
If you need to preserve the exact commit history but want to rebase :
git rebase --onto main <first-merge-base> dev

Hindsight is 20/20, but that doesn't help.
